# Detecting if data exists for OleDB COUNT query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to pull data from ACCESS database.

As it is, the code works, and gives no errors... 
However, I can't seem to be able to display a messagebox if the record doesn't exist. It simply returns an empty string.

```
        Using dbCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = '" & Application.StartupPath & "\Res\T500G.accdb'")

        dbCon.Open()

        Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro=@Pro"

        Dim cmd1 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query1, dbCon)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pro", ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem.ToString)

        Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader


        While reader.Read()

            TextBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString

        End While

        reader.Close()
        dbCon.Close()

    End Using
```

I've tried using `If reader.hasrows then` display result in textbox, else show messagebox etc, but it doesn't work.

```
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()

                TextBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString

            End While
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("asd")

        End If
```

If I remove the `.ToString` from `reader.GetValue(0)` I get an error if the selected item from the combobox doesn't exist in the database. Cannot convert DBNull to integer or something.

So my question is, how to display a messagebox if the record "@Pro" doesn't exist?

Thanks~

**Fixed(Workaround) with this**

```
Dim ValueReturned As String
        While reader.Read()

            ValueReturned = reader.GetValue(0).ToString

            If ValueReturned = "" Then

                MessageBox.Show("Not Found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            Else

                MetroTextBox1.Text = ValueReturned

            End If

        End While
```

Comment: `I've tried using If reader.hasrows then `  you should post that code, clarifying `doesnt work`

Comment: With that kind of query you dont need a reader.  Use `cmd1.ExecuteScalar` instead and capture the return.  There is no need to test `HasRows`, because that query will return 1 value in 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OleDbDataReader` is suboptimal for your query because it is never going to return a set of records to traverse:

```vb
Dim sql = "SELECT SUM(...=@p1"

' rather than sprinkling you connection string all over
' the app, you can make a function returning one
Using conn As OleDbConnection = GetConnection(),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, GetConnection())
    conn.Open())

    ' ToDo: Check that ComboBoxBP.SelectedItems.Count >0 before this
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBoxBP.SelectedItem.ToString)

    ' execute the query, get a result
    Dim total = cmd.ExecuteScalar

    ' if there is no matches, OleDb returns DBNull
    If total Is System.DBNull.Value Then
        ' no matches
        MessageBox.Show("No matching records!"...)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The Total is: " & total.ToString()...)
    End If

End Using   ' disposes of the Connection and Command objects
```

Alteratively, you could use `If IsDBNull(total) Then...`.  If you want, you can also convert it:

```vb
Dim total = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString()
' DBNull will convert to an empty string
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(total) Then
    MessageBox.Show("No Soup For You!")
Else
    ...
End If
```

Comment: My DB has multiple records with the same name inside column @Pro. If the record doesn't exist (on input) it's created. If it exists, it checks the date column, and if the date equals today, the record is updated, if the date is not today, a new one is created. By doing "research" I found out that it's best to use reader for this type of query, since it doesn't keep anything in memory or something. I'll give this a try tho, it seems neat, and clean.

Comment: A reader is good for iterating a result set with mutliple rows.  A `"SELECT SUM...` query can only ever one have one row.  The row will contain only the value or `DBNull` if there are no matching rows.  As such, `ExecuteScalar` returns that sole value without the overhead of a reader.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I'm trying to make it a habit to use functions, or call general things from .dlls so I don't "Sprinkle things all over the app" :D And this is another way to reduce writing the same codes all over again, thanks! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your query to (this is for SQL-Server):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [T500] WHERE Pro = @Pro) SELECT SUM(Total) FROM [T500] WHERE Pro = @Pro ELSE SELECT 'Not Found'
```

And change your code to:

```
    Dim ValueReturned As String
    While reader.Read()

        ValueReturned = reader.GetValue(0).ToString

    End While
    If ValueReturned Is Nothing OrElse ValueReturned = "Not Found" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ValueReturned
    End If
```

Comment: The SQL query didn't work, and the second code had a used variable before it has been assigned a value, but it gave me an idea, and I fixed it. I updated my post. I'll upvote for the inspiration :P

Comment: @Taffs I'm happy you found a solution that works for you. The SQL I put up was for SQL-Server...so probably it did not work because you are using access. Also I corrected the error to my code suggestion. Cheers!